# How to link java scripts and run them within a python script?

Tags: java, python

How to run my java inside of python? I have a discord bot that runs on python but I need to use a script thats only available in Java. How can I import this script and run it?

Comment: You can create a .exe file to run it in windows but what is the purpose of converting in to java ?

Comment: As said, the file is only available in java, I do not know this language I only know python so I cant convert it into python

Comment: Show your code and what you have tried so far. What problem did you run into? If you have don't tried yet, then do that first. The community is here to help solve problems, but not to do your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Jython`

[Jython](https://www.jython.org/) is a Java implementation of Python that combines expressive power with clarity.

**Here is an example of using Java from Python code**

```
from java.lang import System # Java import

print('Running on Java version: ' + System.getProperty('java.version'))
print('Unix time from Java: ' + str(System.currentTimeMillis()))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try pyjnius here is their official site: https://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html
Overview:

pyjnius is a bridge between Python and Java, allowing these to intercommunicate.
It is an effort to allow python programs full access to Java class libraries.